# Irq software in ARM64

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

## Introduction

I am following a tutorial for write Linux Device Driver, the link is the following https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/linux-device-driver-tutorial-part-13-interrupt-example-program-in-linux-kernel/, for this question I am referring to the chapter **Triggering Hardware Interrupt through Software**.

Summarizing in this tutorial it is possible to generate an interrupt via software, the bad news is that this is only shown on x86_64 machines. To do this on an x86_64 system the kernel is modified, introducing changes to the files, this is explained very well in the tutorial. What I want to do, is do the same for ARM64 machine.

### Change Kernel in x86_64

The changes that are made to the kernel are two:

**First Change**

```
--- at/kernel/irq/irqdesc.c
+++ b/kernel/irq/irqdesc.c
@@ -352.7 +352.6 @@ struct irq_desc *irq_to_desc(unsigned in
  {
  return radix_tree_lookup(&irq_desc_tree, irq);
  }
+EXPORT_SYMBOL(irq_to_desc);

  static void delete_irq_desc(unsigned int irq)
  {
```

**Second Change**

In the file `arch/x86/kernel/irq.c` is added

```c
EXPORT_SYMBOL(vector_irq);
```

### IRQ management in the driver

When writing to a char file, the `etx_read` function is executed which generates interrupts.

```c
static ssize_t etx_read(struct file *filp,
                 char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
         struct irq_desc *desc;

         printk(KERN_INFO "Read function\n");
         desc = irq_to_desc(11);
         if (!desc)
         {
             return -EINVAL;
         }
         __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
         asm("int $0x3B"); // Corresponding to irq 11
         return 0;
}
```

ISR is defined like this:

```c
//Interrupt handler for IRQ 11.
static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq,void *dev_id) {
   printk(KERN_INFO "Shared IRQ: Interrupt Occurred");
   return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

The complete code can be found at: https://github.com/orlandonico/Tutorials-embetronicx/blob/master/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c

## My Case

My aim is to go and run the [script](https://github.com/orlandonico/Tutorials-embetronicx/blob/master/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c) on an ARM64 architecture. In particular I use a MacBook with Apple Silicon and to run this tutorial I used an Ubuntu Server VM for ARM64.

```bash
dooraim@ubuntu-2202:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-2202 5.15.0-71-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 18 09:00:08 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

What I expected to do was follow the tutorial just like I did in the case of machine x86_64, but this I can't do since I can't find the functions used above in the case of x86_64.

If I try to compile the [script](https://github.com/orlandonico/Tutorials-embetronicx/blob/master/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c) i have the following error (of course the interrupt line is incorrect)

```
dooraim@ubuntu-2202:~/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-71-generic/build  M=/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.o
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/percpu.h:248,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/smp.h:28,
                 from ./include/linux/smp.h:114,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h:18,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/timex.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from ./include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/stat.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c:13:
/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c: In function ‘etx_rea’:
/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c:132:26: error: ‘vector_irq’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘sector_t’?
  132 |         __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:219:54: note: in definition of macro ‘__verify_pcpu_ptr’
  219 |         const void __percpu *__vpp_verify = (typeof((ptr) + 0))NULL;    \
      |                                                      ^~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:421:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
  421 | #define raw_cpu_write(pcp, val)         __pcpu_size_call(raw_cpu_write_, pcp, val)
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:452:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_write’
  452 |         raw_cpu_write(pcp, val);                                        \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c:132:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_write’
  132 |         __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c:132:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  132 |         __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:219:54: note: in definition of macro ‘__verify_pcpu_ptr’
  219 |         const void __percpu *__vpp_verify = (typeof((ptr) + 0))NULL;    \
      |                                                      ^~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:421:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
  421 | #define raw_cpu_write(pcp, val)         __pcpu_size_call(raw_cpu_write_, pcp, val)
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:452:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_write’
  452 |         raw_cpu_write(pcp, val);                                        \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c:132:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_write’
  132 |         __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1907: /home/dooraim/Tutorials-embetronicx/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

I've tried compiling the kernel with the changes made in the case of x86_64, but there's no point in doing so.

## Question

Does anyone know how interrupts work on ARM64 platforms? Could it help me to figure out how to implement something like [script](https://github.com/orlandonico/Tutorials-embetronicx/blob/master/Linux/Device_Driver/Interrupt-in-Linux-Kernel/New-Kernel-Example/driver.c) above?

I hope I was clear, if so, ask me.

Comment: All of the x86_64 stuff looks wrong to me. You shouldn't try to directly overwrite interrupts, you should use the kernel's interrupt system to register your interrupt handler.